# Azure DevOps - Unable to Upload Artifacts on JFrog Repository

Tags: azure-pipelines, artifactory, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using Azure DevOps 2020 as a CI tools and in it I am using **Artifactory Generic Upload** plugin to upload my artifacts to the **Pdspsp-generic-snapshot-local** repository.
While executing the pipeline I am getting below error and I am unable to upload any artifacts to the repo.

Can anyone please let me know the reason for the **"503 Service Unavailable"** and **[Error]** **read tcp 10.7.208.39:52330->40.70.153.149:443: wsarecv: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine** **error**?

However, the same set of task works on other server but fails on this azure server. Also I am able to manually log into Jfrog artifactory from this server but while executing this task via CI getting this error.

[image]

[image]

Pasting the debug log below for reference,

```
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9377067Z ##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'Artifactory Generic Upload'
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9385324Z ##[debug]Evaluating: succeeded()
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9386860Z ##[debug]Evaluating succeeded:
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9389126Z ##[debug]=> True
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9395246Z ##[debug]Result: True
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9402084Z ##[section]Starting: Artifactory Generic Upload
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9849680Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9850091Z Task         : Artifactory Generic Upload
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9850644Z Description  : Upload build artifacts to Artifactory using FileSpecs while allowing to collect build-info. The collected build-info can be later published to Artifactory by the "Artifactory Publish Build Info" task.
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9851203Z Version      : 2.12.3
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9851425Z Author       : JFrog
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9851670Z Help         : 
2022-03-21T14:17:46.9851951Z ==============================================================================
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2651262Z ##[debug]agent.TempDirectory=E:\Cache\Agent04\_temp
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2688167Z ##[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2695323Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2722852Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0_PASSWORD
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2728423Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0_USERNAME
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2731679Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2735070Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2737641Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2740538Z ##[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2743835Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_ARTIFACTORYSERVICE
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2746190Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_BUILDNAME
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2748667Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_BUILDNUMBER
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2751218Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_COLLECTBUILDINFO
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2754363Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_DRYRUN
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2757202Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FAILNOOP
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2759736Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FILE
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2762242Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_FILESPEC
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2766018Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_INCLUDEENVVARS
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2769136Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_INSECURETLS
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2771647Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_REPLACESPECVARS
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2775240Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_RETRIES
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2778185Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SETDEBIANPROPS
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2781657Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SPECSOURCE
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2784998Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SYMLINKS
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2788331Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_SYNCDELETES
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2790942Z ##[debug]loading INPUT_THREADS
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2799323Z ##[debug]loaded 24
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2821748Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2823897Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2824458Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.2824844Z ##[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3646837Z ##[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3647796Z ##[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3648419Z ##[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3651599Z ##[debug]check path : E:\Cache\Agent04\_tasks\ArtifactoryGenericUpload_07fc5c20-6772-11e5-abde-6901d3d00475\2.12.3\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tool-lib\lib.json
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3654658Z ##[debug]adding resource file: E:\Cache\Agent04\_tasks\ArtifactoryGenericUpload_07fc5c20-6772-11e5-abde-6901d3d00475\2.12.3\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tool-lib\lib.json
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3662117Z ##[debug]system.culture=en-US
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3974536Z ##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3978295Z ##[debug]Agent.WorkFolder=E:\Cache\Agent04
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3987013Z ##[debug]JFROG_CLI_PIPELINE_REQUESTED_VERSION_AZURE=undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3998758Z ##[debug]isExplicit: 1.47.1
2022-03-21T14:17:49.3999320Z ##[debug]explicit? true
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4000993Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.170.1
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4001550Z ##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4002005Z ##[debug]checking cache: E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4004327Z ##[debug]not found
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4043517Z ##[debug]
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4045329Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.170.1
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4045838Z ##[debug]Agent.TempDirectory=E:\Cache\Agent04\_temp
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4048459Z ##[debug]testing directory 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_temp'
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4084741Z Downloading: https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/jfrog-cli/v1/1.47.1/jfrog-cli-windows-amd64/jfrog.exe
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4085795Z ##[debug]destination E:\Cache\Agent04\_temp\58c85376-ec1f-42ba-a8d9-7b0b334e8f98
2022-03-21T14:17:49.4086352Z ##[debug]downloading
2022-03-21T14:17:49.8616353Z ##[debug]creating stream
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6308932Z ##[debug]download complete
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6314328Z Caching tool: jfrog 1.47.1 x64
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6315102Z ##[debug]source file:E:\Cache\Agent04\_temp\58c85376-ec1f-42ba-a8d9-7b0b334e8f98
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6318429Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.170.1
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6318962Z ##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6319744Z ##[debug]destination E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6322571Z ##[debug]rm -rf E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6325935Z ##[debug]rm -rf E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64.complete
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6327931Z ##[debug]testing directory 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64'
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6329461Z ##[debug]testing directory 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1'
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6331498Z ##[debug]testing directory 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog'
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6333307Z ##[debug]testing directory 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool'
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6335436Z ##[debug]mkdir 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog'
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6340280Z ##[debug]mkdir 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1'
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6344280Z ##[debug]mkdir 'E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64'
2022-03-21T14:17:50.6350197Z ##[debug]destination fileE:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64\jfrog.exe
2022-03-21T14:17:50.9985781Z ##[debug]Agent.Version=2.170.1
2022-03-21T14:17:50.9987833Z ##[debug]Agent.ToolsDirectory=E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool
2022-03-21T14:17:50.9996407Z ##[debug]finished caching tool
2022-03-21T14:17:50.9999214Z ##[debug]Finished downloading JFrog cli.
2022-03-21T14:17:51.0002129Z Running jfrog-cli from E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64\jfrog.exe.
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4652787Z JFrog CLI version: 1.47.1
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4654868Z ##[debug]set JFROG_CLI_TASK_SELECTED_VERSION_AZURE=1.47.1
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4658077Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=JFROG_CLI_TASK_SELECTED_VERSION_AZURE;isOutput=false;issecret=false;]1.47.1
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4659064Z ##[debug]System.DefaultWorkingDirectory=E:\Cache\Agent04\1\s
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4672843Z ##[debug]artifactoryService=f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4674974Z ##[debug]f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0=https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4681746Z ##[debug]f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0 auth param username = ***
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4683588Z ##[debug]f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0 auth param password = ***
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4684160Z ##[debug]f12720bc-55c3-41bd-b338-ec6857ccf5a0 auth param apitoken = undefined
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4692036Z ##[debug]specSource=taskConfiguration
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4692773Z ##[debug]fileSpec={
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "F:/Demo/21.4.1.2.zip",
      "target": "Pdspsp-generic-snapshot-local/"
    }
  ]
}
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4693509Z Using file spec:
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4697004Z {
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4697193Z   "files": [
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4697360Z     {
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4697604Z       "pattern": "F:/Demo/21.4.1.2.zip",
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4697909Z       "target": "Pdspsp-generic-snapshot-local/"
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4698151Z     }
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4698295Z   ]
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4698452Z }
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4707092Z ##[debug]replaceSpecVars=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4710642Z ##[debug]collectBuildInfo=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4715364Z ##[debug]failNoOp=true
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4717024Z ##[debug]dryRun=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4720736Z ##[debug]insecureTls=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4722854Z ##[debug]syncDeletes=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4727287Z ##[debug]threads=3
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4730514Z ##[debug]retries=3
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4733547Z ##[debug]symlinks=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4739684Z ##[debug]setDebianProps=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.4746501Z ##[debug]Executing cliCommand: E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64\jfrog.exe rt u --url="https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory" --user=*** --password=*** --spec="E:\Cache\Agent04\1\s\uploadSpec1647872272464.json" --fail-no-op=true --dry-run=false --insecure-tls=false --threads=3 --retries=3 --symlinks=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.5719941Z [Info] [Thread 2] Uploading artifact: F:\Demo\21.4.1.2.zip
2022-03-21T14:17:52.6843891Z [Warn] [Thread 2] The server response: 503 Service Unavailable
2022-03-21T14:17:52.6845714Z [Warn] [Thread 2] Attempt 0 - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory/Pdspsp-generic-snapshot-local/21.4.1.2.zip;;;
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7236481Z [Warn] [Thread 2] The server response: 503 Service Unavailable
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7237412Z [Warn] [Thread 2] Attempt 1 - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory/Pdspsp-generic-snapshot-local/21.4.1.2.zip;;;
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7569997Z [Warn] [Thread 2] Attempt 2 - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory/Pdspsp-generic-snapshot-local/21.4.1.2.zip;;; - read tcp 10.7.208.39:52329->40.70.153.149:443: wsarecv: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7887136Z [Warn] [Thread 2] Attempt 3 - Failure occurred while uploading to https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory/Pdspsp-generic-snapshot-local/21.4.1.2.zip;;; - read tcp 10.7.208.39:52330->40.70.153.149:443: wsarecv: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7888698Z [Error] Failed uploading 1 artifacts.
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7889539Z [Error] read tcp 10.7.208.39:52330->40.70.153.149:443: wsarecv: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7890156Z {
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7890343Z   "status": "failure",
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7890556Z   "totals": {
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7890747Z     "success": 0,
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7890964Z     "failure": 0
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7891134Z   }
2022-03-21T14:17:52.7891289Z }
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9024961Z [Error] Upload finished with errors, Please review the logs.
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9118759Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9166577Z ##[error]Error: Command failed: E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64\jfrog.exe rt u --url="https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory" --user=*** --password=*** --spec="E:\Cache\Agent04\1\s\uploadSpec1647872272464.json" --fail-no-op=true --dry-run=false --insecure-tls=false --threads=3 --retries=3 --symlinks=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9179123Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: Command failed: E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64\jfrog.exe rt u --url="https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory" --user=*** --password=*** --spec="E:\Cache\Agent04\1\s\uploadSpec1647872272464.json" --fail-no-op=true --dry-run=false --insecure-tls=false --threads=3 --retries=3 --symlinks=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9196719Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Error: Command failed: E:\Cache\Agent04\_tool\jfrog\1.47.1\x64\jfrog.exe rt u --url="https://artifactory.fis.dev/artifactory" --user=*** --password=*** --spec="E:\Cache\Agent04\1\s\uploadSpec1647872272464.json" --fail-no-op=true --dry-run=false --insecure-tls=false --threads=3 --retries=3 --symlinks=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9200472Z ##[debug]rm -rf E:\Cache\Agent04\1\s\uploadSpec1647872272464.json
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9200994Z ##[debug]removing file E:\Cache\Agent04\1\s\uploadSpec1647872272464.json
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9780317Z ##[debug]task result: Succeeded
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9791933Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Succeeded;]Build Succeeded.
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9810782Z ##[debug]includeEnvVars=false
2022-03-21T14:17:52.9956076Z ##[section]Finishing: Artifactory Generic Upload
```

Comment: From the logs provided it is hard to know why you received the 503 error. 
Can you provide more information from the application logs? 

I would suggest you to try to reproduce and tail both artifactory.log (in Artiactory 6.x) artifactory-service.log (in 7.x) and the request.log (in artifactory 6.x) artifactory-request.log and look for the 503 error. 

Please update here with your findings.

Answer (score 1):

For good measure to ensure your credentials and endpoints are correct you can try this in an yml pipeline, the following task should work for uploading.

```yaml
- task: ArtifactoryGenericUpload@2
  inputs:
    artifactoryService: '<connection>'
    specSource: 'taskConfiguration'
    fileSpec: |
      {
         "files": [
            {
            "pattern": "./out.zip",
            "target": "where/iwanttouploadto/main"
                  }
              ]
       }
    collectBuildInfo: true
    buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
    buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    failNoOp: true
```